# How to un-downvote a down-vote by mistake?

Tags: support

Apparently I accidentally downvoted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266108/create-two-automapper-maps-between-the-same-two-object-types/14268378#14268378). I did not realize that I did that until now - when I looked at my rep history and saw -1. I remember reading this answer earlier today but I had no intention to downvote it.

When I try to upvote it back the system says that the vote is locked and cannot be changed unless the answer is edited.

Should I just forget this unhappy incident and move along? I'm not worried about loss of 1 rep, I'm worried that it's unfair toward a perfectly good answer and its author.