# I downvoted a correct answer due to misunderstanding it

Tags: support, downvotes

I downvoted an answer intentionally, but moments later I realized that I had misunderstood the answer.

I have referred to these posts already. [Post1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300417/how-to-un-downvote-a-down-vote-by-mistake)   [Post2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270364/accidental-downvote-realised-after-two-hours).

In these cases, they downvoted it accidentally, but in my case it was intentional (**but by** ***misunderstanding*** **the answer**). The mistake was mine.

It is not fair to ask the answerer to edit a good answer. The person seems to be an emerging user, so it would easily discourage them.

Can I lose points for my mistake and how to undo this without editing [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66593032/how-to-run-a-for-loop-using-a-variable-with-value-determined-by-prompt/66593079#66593079)?

Comment: An off-note: when editing, please also remove the "thanks" comments - they are pure noise (since you edited out other noise, I approved the edit and removed the abovementioned).

Comment: When you say "moments later," do you mean that literally? There's a five minute window after voting where you can still change it without editing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I appreciate you having the author's interests as an emerging user in mind, and wanting to make amends. I believe users should be able to undo their own downvotes on a case-by-case basis, given a valid reason. The vote lock is there to prevent abuse such as repeatedly toggling their downvote over an extended period of time.

Whether you cast the downvote as a result of a misclick or misjudgement, we've all been there. Since you've linked to the specific answer you voted on, I've edited it so you can remove your downvote (I've added syntax highlighting that, while not essential, is still a good thing to have). You won't lose any rep beyond the 1 you spent to cast the downvote, which will be reimbursed once you've removed it.