# What should you do with users who won't help unless you upvote?

Tags: discussion, code-of-conduct, specific-user

I googled a problem and came across a relevant question with an accepted answer by user A. User B pointed out a better way (in their opinion) of solving the problem in a comment, which was also upvoted. A didn't edit their answer and B didn't go further into it, so I pinged B in a comment and asked about more details. User A replied:

> Upvote the answer and I'll edit it to include the other way too.

How do you deal with users like that? Do you just flag the comment?

Comment: You ignore them and mod-flag their answer and explain what happened. This type of behavior is NOT okay, and normal comment flags don't do it justice. There's also a chance a user doing this has done it several times, meaning mods can take appropriate action (such as warning or banning, depending on various circumstances)

Comment: Ask B to write a new answer perhaps. Or write your own answer based on B's solution (with attribution, consider making it community wiki also).

Comment: huh? Why didn't user B post this in as an answer instead? Why should we force people to edit their answer? Then downvote user A's answer (if you think it's not the right way to do it) and upvote user B's answer.

Comment: Upvote, wait for them to edit, then undo your upvote and replace with a downvote

Comment: @Zoe User A deleted the comment after about 30 minutes (maybe because I didn't reply?), will mods still be able to see it?

Comment: Mods can see deleted comments.

Comment: This seems like it is an omission in the code of conduct to be honest. Right now I feel it would be a little hard to prove that actually anything bad has been done. Voting fraud is not allowed but can we really back up that cheekily asking for a single upvote is voting fraud? There is no entry on the CoC which prohibits making these kind of "payment" requests that I can see.

Comment: Upvotes are anonymous anyway, as all score related votes are; how does the user in question know you haven't already upvoted their answer (unless there are no votes on the answer)? I'm not saying you should because they asked you to, but they have no idea if you have or not once there is *at least* 1 upvote on it.

Comment: @Larnu The answer only has a few upvotes and you are notified when someone upvotes on of your answer. You can't see who it was of course but in this case it would be easy to guess that it was me.

Comment: You get notified, yes, but again, they have no idea if *you* haven't (up)voted it in the past. Just because you have engaged in the answer now doesn't mean you hadn't read and upvoted it previously.

Comment: @Nick Wouldn't that be abusing the system though? If someone improves their answer and the edit works better than their original version, it would certainly be worth an upvote because in the end you're voting on their answer, not their behavior.

Comment: @Neph *"you're voting on their answer, not their behavior."* - If only the site were that black and white. Users can and do vote for whatever reason they choose, even if it's not always for the reasons prescribed in the vote tooltip

Comment: @Nick So you would downvote a good and working answer if the author acted inappropriately in the comments?

Comment: @Neph Me personally? That depends on a lot more than if the answer is good and working, if it were posted on a blatant duplicate by someone that should know better, sure, if it were a good answer on a novel question? Probably not, I'd just flag the comments and move along

Comment: I've seen a fair share of "please upvote" requests (which are, imo, rather harmless and easy to clean up), but this is just petty. The only worse thing to do would be to say "upvote or I will delete the answer" :(

Comment: "How do you deal with users like that?" I aim badly at the upvote button, maybe kind of slip half an inch downwards.

Comment: @Nick [that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407055/what-should-you-do-with-users-who-wont-help-unless-you-upvote?cb=1#comment839063_407055) is the perfect amount of petty.

Comment: Seems to be a lot of opinion around whether it's ok or not to ask for an upvote before updating an answer. But is there an official stance on this to remove all the subjective discussions?

Comment: I can't see why it's wrong, no-one is forcing you to upvote, the same as no-one is forcing them to update their answer. They could have not replied at all and left the answer as it is. If the answer is not a good answer or bad etc, then downvote it. If the answer is good as it stands then there's no problem upvoting it. If the upvote also brings you additional info then great. Otherwise, move on I guess..

Comment: @James: I guess it's not blatantly wrong, but it does really push it, and it's kind of a dick move to withhold information not just from the question asker but from all other readers (even if it's not forcing them to upvote, it is at the very least coercing them to upvote by leaving the answer worse off for everyone if they choose not to). Certainly a user with a pattern of doing this in exchange for votes ought to be paid a visit from us...

Comment: @OlegValter I've seen that happen twice now. A user asking for an accept on their Answer or they'll delete it. The Answer in both cases were deleted and the comment removed.

Comment: @James No, nobody is forcing anyone to edit their question/write an answer but if nobody ever helped anyone, stackoverflow,... wouldn't exist. If you comment without providing too much detail, then don't be surprised if someone asks for more details. In my case user B left a comment, I pinged them but user A replied and told me to basically "upvote or I won't help you". If you don't want to help, great, don't, but as BoltClock said, holding information hostage like that is just a dick move, it's like a child saying: "I've got a lollipop and you don't, nananana-na-naaaa *sticks out tongue*!"

Comment: @Scratte gosh, what the world to live in. Why even bother helping when one is so hell-bent on getting the sweet gamification that they are willing to remove what they already published (a rhetorical question)? It is really petty

Comment: @Oleg Valter, Scratte: I've also seen the complete opposite: askers maliciously keeping incorrect answers accepted so answerers can't self-delete. Good thing moderators can delete and undelete accepted answers as they please...

Comment: @BoltClock - now you are sucking the hope for humanity out of me :( That's a strange tactic, though - so you say that the *asker* posts an incorrect solution, accepts it and then keeps it to prevent others from removing content?

Comment: @Oleg Valter: No, the asker keeps someone else's answer to their question accepted. Usually accompanied by taunting comments when the answerer pleads with them to unaccept so they can delete and avoid getting any more downvotes.

Comment: @BoltClock jeez that's awful, admittedly even more so than withholding additional information...

Comment: *Upvote, wait for them to edit...* @Nick Assuming they actually do edit it. I assume the scam here is that they say they’ll do something in exchange for an up vote and then never do, knowing you can’t undo your vote without an edit. And unless you have over 2K rep, which the OP doesn’t, you can’t edit it yourself to fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Votes on a post should be contingent only on your personal assessment of its own merits. They should not be contingent on any of the following:

- The post author or other users
- Other posts (e.g. downvoting an answer because the question is off-topic or because the author left an objectionable comment under their own answer or anyone else's)
- Other votes (e.g. I'll upvote you if and only if you upvote me)
- Actions promised but not yet fulfilled (e.g. asking for votes in exchange for a new answer or an edit to an existing answer)

While we can't enforce how anyone uses every one of their votes because individual votes are anonymous and we can't police anyone's free will, we do have rules, boundaries and mechanisms in place to maintain a more-or-less level playing field.

Having said that, withholding an answer or new information in an answer in exchange for your upvote is insidious because it hurts not only you, but also [any future readers viewing the question](https://xkcd.com/979). To make it simply about any one particular reader and their vote is selfish and goes against the spirit of Stack Overflow as a Q&A knowledgebase for all. In the long run, it also hurts the answerer because they're giving up any potential future upvotes they could've received had they just shared the knowledge, just because of *one* upvote (that they have no way of verifying was from you to begin with).

So when someone tells you in a comment that they'll edit their answer to add new information if and only if you upvote it first, how do you respond? Well, you could flag it and forget about it, if the user doesn't seem like they'd be amenable to reason.

Otherwise, you could try asserting in a reply that it's not appropriate to ask for votes in exchange for new information in an answer. Or you could just link to *this* answer. If they refuse to budge, well, as petty as this may sound you reserve the right to downvote the answer if it's simply detrimental or not useful to you the way it is. But also don't feel compelled to vote if you simply don't wish to deal with any potential consequences. Just move on in that case.

In this specific situation, user B is innocent. However, the fact that a third party has an idea of what the better solution is indicates that there's still hope that someone else might come along and share it. I do recommend the approach in [D. SM's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407055/what-should-you-do-with-users-who-wont-help-unless-you-upvote/407107#407107) of asking a new question — it is OK to ask follow-up questions branching off of existing, answered ones, with links for context (though do be careful, questions about improving on existing, *working* solutions tend to go on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead). If user A refuses to share, it's their loss.

If someone is engaging in a *pattern* of demanding votes from other users this way, flag their answer for moderator attention and we'll speak to them. This is definitely not behavior we want to encourage on Stack Overflow, for the reasons I explained above.

We don't want to encourage anyone to upvote first in such a situation either, because there's a chance the user may not honor their end of the bargain. And if you don't retract your upvote within five minutes, it gets locked in until either the post author finally makes good and edits their answer, or you raise a flag and [a moderator makes a stub edit to free your vote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405922/i-downvoted-a-correct-answer-due-to-misunderstanding-it/405923#405923) (or you come here making a stink about it and someone with the right privileges does so). Abuse potential aside, the vote you deposited doesn't reflect your opinion of the post *in its actual state*, and getting it removed is just unnecessary hassle for everyone but the answerer.

Answer (score 12):

**Asking for votes is never ok,** no matter what the circumstances are. Votes are meant to represent your personal opinion of the usefulness of the content.

If you see someone asking for votes, flag such comments as no longer needed or in more extreme situations raise a mod flag on one of the posts (not a comment).

Comment: I disagree with "**never** ok". OP: "This is excellent, thank you so much!" Answerer: "Thanks, glad it worked. Feel free to upvote and accept it as the correct answer if you feel it properly solved your issue." If you think that 99% of the participators on this site aren't at least partially motivated by the gamification then I have some land to sell you located in the Pacific Ocean.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I always immediately flag such comments as NLN. They are not helpful to me or anyone else. They look like someone is begging for votes or acceptance. It is OP's choice whether they vote or accept and we can't ask them to do so

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I would say it's okay to ask for your answer to be ACCEPTED, but not upvoted. If it helped the OP, it should be accepted, but not necessarily upvoted as being accepted doesn't mean it is high quality.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 The upvote tooltip makes no mention of "quality".

Comment: I just put a link to [a help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if I think someone doesn't know what to do about answers they've received. Much less garish that outright begging for acceptance/upvoting.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 - I would also flag as NLN a comment that asks for their answer to be accepted.  That's not "OK" in my books either.  Or even one that asks for someone else's answer to be accepted.  However, I have no problem with people >>silently<< deciding not to help people who appear ungrateful ... by what ever criteria they judge that.

Comment: @Dharman They are slightly important. If an answer is useful and helped the OP then they should know to accept it and upvote if they have enough rep. Once they do that the comments should then be flagged and deleted.

Comment: I agree with @MonkeyZeus insofar that it's acceptable and possibly even encouraged to gently introduce new users to the upvote and accept features in hopes they'll exercise them in future. I wouldn't flag those comments *immediately* - they aren't breaking any rules, and the example MonkeyZeus gave certainly doesn't "look" anything like begging to me. Not sure why people keep thinking that by asking or directing them to the features we are necessarily being demanding. Context and tone matter.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus it's not only gamification, but it's also content rating. If an answer is actually an answer to a question in almost all cases, then upvoting and accepting will not only help the OP, but it will also help future users as they know that the answer is actually helpful.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus what if while helpful, it didn't solve my problem? How about if they have 3000 questions and all of them but the one I'm answering have upvotes or accepted? What if there are better answers posted? What if they never comment?

Comment: @Braiam What part of "**if you feel it properly solved your issue**" was confusing exactly?

Comment: @NicholasHunter If you know this is their first time you can post a link to the help section under their question, but in general it is not your job to teach them about the site. Stack Overflow should do a better job at educating users on how the site works before letting them post here.

Comment: a small note to folks using canned comments to "teach" the OP as I see the from time to time: please account for the fact that upvoting is a privilege at 15 rep, far from all new users even *can* upvote (although they can accept).

Comment: @MonkeyZeus "Feel free to upvote and accept it as the correct answer if you feel it properly solved your issue." I'm not totally against it, but I wonder if the opposite would then be okay too: "This answer doesn't seem to properly answer the question. Anyone, if you feel the same, you're invited to downvote it." Could be seen as just teaching people who recently earned the downvote privilege how to use the site.

Comment: @Dharman see the *"if clause"* in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297598). I've pinged countless users (some of them high reps) who simply forgot to accept and upvote an answer (after explicitly stating in the comments it had solved their problem). It's also reasonable to ask a user for feedback on an answer if after 30 days they didn't react in anyway (seems folks have a tendency to forget about answers after they've gotten the solution to their problem). There's also a number of users who ignore any answer they get, asking them why is within reasonable.

Comment: @Trilarion I'd agree if we were talking about unprompted "if this solved your problem" comments. But that's quite a bit different from one in a response to the OP. "This is excellent, thank you so much!" isn't technically an appropriate use of comments (its not doing anything to improve the answer). By making the comment instead of upvoting/accepting, the OP is demonstrating that they may be unaware of the existing formal mechanisms SO has to express that sentiment. So education in that context is different than unprompted educating of random general passersby.

Comment: Accepting and upvoting are two independent actions. If the answer solved my problem then I will accept it, and users should be encouraged to accept answers that solve the problem. But accepting an answer does not mean that it needs to, or even should, be upvoted.

Comment: @Dharman You should be reprimanded then. I only hope mods are declining your flags. Such comments are *exceedingly* useful to users who are unfamiliar with the site and who don't understand the importance of making sure to use these features. There is nothing wrong with reminding someone to use the site as it was intended.

Comment: @jpmc mods can't decline them because the system deletes them with a single flag. The ones that somehow get through to the mods are always deleted too. This is how the site was designed to work. Comments are temporary. If you want to post a link to help page then remember to remove it 15 minutes later

Comment: Just want to add that about half of the times I answered a "thank you so much!!!" with a "you're welcome, if it helped please accept", the followup was "how do I do that?".

Comment: @ItamarMushkin - that's another testament to how bad the current new user onboarding is... I'd like to see how many of our problems could simply go poof if the onboarding was integrated into the site experience and not delegated to an optional completely useless and misrepresenting tour. [reposted, editorial fix]

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 - _… accepting an answer does not mean that it needs to, or even should, be upvoted._ – If accepting an answer means _the answer solved my problem_, claiming that it is not necessarily **useful** makes no sense (to me, at least).

Comment: @MonkeyZeus the part where I'm still demanding action of another user? People are free to vote however they want, and that's something that is built in the system. Trying to get them to vote one way or another for any means is not recommended. Use comments to suggest improvements on the post, not to talk about votes.

Comment: @Armali if accepting an answer must always upvote, that would have been a function of the site. It isn't, therefore suggesting that accepting and upvoting are separate things. You could get an unsatisfactory answer that just happens the only one (perhaps so far). And "useful" is a subjective metric. I see many questions that are accurate or solve a problem but not all of them are *useful*.

Comment: @VLAZ - It is (at least in my view) a contradiction for an answer to be _unsatisfactory_ (your wording) and _solved my problem_ (rink.attendant.6's wording), hence I can't follow the logic. I really can't see how something that solves a problem is not useful.

Comment: @Armali if a pipe bursts, I can stuff an entire pie where a leak is, that solves the problem *for now* but I'll probably have more problems in the future. I also lose an entire pie. It's an unsatisfactory solution.

Comment: Excuse the nitpicking, but the point in question is not the correlation between _solves the problem_ and _satisfactory_, but between _solves the problem_ and _useful_, which your metaphor doesn't address, while it serves to resolve my other issue.

Comment: I am a little displeased. I haven't done it but I've considered replying to a "thanks" comment from a new user whose question I answered with a comment along the lines of "upvotes make me happy". Part of the idea is the new user doesn't know how the site works yet.

Comment: @Armali **a** solution is not necessarily a **useful** solution. "Solves the problem" is not a very useful metric to me if I've lost my pie and would face the same issue in the future. I'd prefer to solve the problem for the future as well *and* get to eat my pie. That would be useful to me.

Comment: @VLAZ - I'm afraid we must agree to disagree. For you, a solution limited in time or associated with costs seems _not_ _useful_, while for me even a limited solution clearly is _useful_ because it is a solution, hence has the use of solving the problem - and that independently of the existence of or the wish for more useful alternatives.

Comment: @Trilarion: I mean, I know of some YouTubers who encourage viewers to press dislike if they disliked the video for whatever reason, so this wouldn't be much different to that. But in my experience, on Stack Exchange, people figure out the downvote feature by proxy of the upvote feature long before they even gain the privilege to cast downvotes.

Comment: Anyway I like how this entire thread has devolved into people arguing over which of a post's qualities should be considered for votes, when the original point of the question was the act of withholding information based on another user's use of votes that has nothing to do with their post's own merits, all because of a sweeping statement in the answer.

Comment: @Dharman You're avoiding defending your position. You said, "They are not helpful to me or anyone else. They look like someone is begging for votes or acceptance. It is OP's choice whether they vote or accept and we can't ask them to do so." That is *wrong,* period, for the reasons I laid our previously. The ephemeral nature of comments is utterly irrelevant to your claim or mine. You're abusing your flagging privileges, and you openly admit to doing so repeatedly.

Comment: For me it really depends on the situation: Let's say user C posts an answer, answers all of your other questions and helps fix your problem. If you then say "thanks, that really helped me" without accepting the answer, imo it's okay for C to reply with "I'm glad it helped, I'd be happy if you accepted this answer/left an upvote", which is the same as a youtuber asking for likes/a sub if you enjoy their video. In my question I addressed a completely different situation though: User A asked for a like in exchange for an answer, so basically "upvote or I won't help" (btw: no, he didn't help).

Comment: "it is OP's choice whether they vote or accept and we can't ask them to do so" asking them doesn't negate their choice to do so or not. Also, the site is really driven by things such as rep and the goodies more rep gives you like access to things. If more rep is useful and encouraged and promoted, what's wrong with people asking politely? (nothing to do with the question here, but you posted "never")

Answer (score 6):

If you are asking about what the "right" thing to do is, I suggest:

**If you feel that the comment can be incorporated into the existing answer in a way that the author of the answer will agree with, edit the answer to be what you think it should be.**

Why are you making the original author  perform this work, when you are the one benefitting from the information provided? You can show your gratitude by contributing to the site.

Conversely, if you can't think of how to incorporate the new content in a non-objectionable manner, the original author may well have a similar issue which is why the comment is a comment and not edited into the answer.

(IIRC under 2k rep your edit will go in the queue which is annoying, but you are asking about the "right" thing to do, so this is how the site works.)

Edit for comment:

> User B's comment only hints at what he thinks is a better way. He didn't give more details, so I don't know how much of his and user A's solution have in common. I also don't know how to do user B's approach, that's why I wrote the comment in the first place (as mentioned in my question).

A question was asked, this question was answered (by user A) and the answer was accepted. Someone (user B) suggested an alternate approach. That, in my understanding of how the site works, *should have* been its own answer, but user B didn't bother making their comment into an answer for whatever reason. Now, you see this and request user A perform work *for you specifically* (not for the original asker) in a way that doesn't comply with the format of the site.

- If you have the same problem as stated in the question, and the accepted answer works for you, your problem is solved and user A's job is done.
- If you have a different problem that the accepted answer does not work for, I think you should **ask a new question** stating your problem, referencing the existing question and explaining the difference.
- If you have the same problem as stated in the question and you are curious about the comment, you can also **ask a new question** specifically about this comment. You may have to put some effort into phrasing your question as a high enough quality question to be suitable for the site.

Comment: User B's comment only hints at what he thinks is a better way. He didn't give more details, so I don't know how much of his and user A's solution have in common. I also don't know how to do user B's approach, that's why I wrote the comment in the first place (as mentioned in my question). In the end editing the answer is out of question and not necessarily what I asked about.

Comment: Re _you see this and request user A perform work_ - OP said "... so I pinged B ..." so no, they asked B to expand on their comment.  That A chimed in and offered that expansion for a reward is not the OPs (of this meta Q) fault.  That said, asking a new question, focused on B's suggested method, is the way to go.

Comment: `you see this and request user A perform work for you specifically` - No, I didn't, I asked user B for more details. This (^) question isn't about how to deal with user B hinting at an alternative (possible better) solution or what to do with user A's existing and accepted answer (that could maybe be expanded). The question is about users holding information hostage. Please read my first post again.

Comment: No user is *obligated* to answer your, or any, questions here.  "holding information hostage"? Is that like being a criminal?

Comment: @D.SM No, nobody has to reply, edit their post or write an answer, you're right about that. "Do ... or else I won't ..." is exactly what hostage situations are about and while in this case it's fortunately not meant in a criminal way, doing this on a website that only exists for asking questions and giving/receiving answers is borderline rule-breaking as others here have already pointed out. In the end this question isn't about "mooooom, he didn't help me set up my toy!" or trying to get him to edit his post, as I've said multiple times before.

Comment: This site does not *only* exist to ask questions. You think it's a support forum and it isn't. As an asker you have a number of responsibilities including phrasing the question clearly, making it objectively answerable, etc. This also includes following other rules like not asking for 1 on 1 support which you are trying to do.

Comment: @D.SM Stackoverflow,... are about asking questions and writing answers, that's the sole purpose for most people and that's what the website gets its clicks for. Where did I ever say that I was asking for 1:1 support? I asked user B to give more information about a possible alternative he posted, which would also benefit others coming across this question. You keep making stuff up and are constantly trying to get into specifics that don't matter for this question. User A asked for likes in exchange for an edit, that's what I asked about, not if/how I should edit their answer.